# Electric field inside a wire connected to a battery

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, potential

Why is the electric field in a current carrying wire always in the direction of its tangent no matter how we bend the wire?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from Ohm’s law. Ohm’s law says $\vec J =\sigma \vec E$. So the current density $\vec J$ is parallel to the electric field $\vec E$. Since the current density always points in the longitudinal direction, so does the E field.

Comment: Current density points in longitudinal direction because current travels in longitudinal direction. Why does current travel in longitudinal direction?

Comment: That is the only direction that it can travel to make a complete circuit. If it tried to travel any other direction then it would run into the surface of the wire and stop. That would deposit charge on the surface which would repel the charge carriers away from the surface.

Comment: If it runs on the surface of the wire why would it stop?

Comment: Can it cross the wire surface? Of no then why?

Comment: @SanjoyKundu that would make a good question